# Is there a way to update/re-generate .cshtml files on Visual Studio (the ones generated when adding controller)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I updated my .edmx model file and now I want the generated edit.cshtml file and create.cshtml files updated according to it. Is there a way to get it done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What i'd do is:

1. Backup related data from controllers and views.
2. Delete Views and Controllers that you need to generate
3. Create controllers with use of same scaffolding you used before.
4. Generate views for controllers using that scaffolding
5. Use your backup to update all that controller/views with logic that you had before (or skip this step if you don't need that).

Comment: Not sure if it's possible :\

Comment: Failing that, create a new controller, point it at your updated model, copy/paste the bits you want, then delete the new controller